# View data not showing after moving website

Tags: views

I just move a drupal 7 website from my localhost WAMP server to a production server (using phpmyadmin for the database).

Everything is fine except the views which didn't show anything. The data are here but even with the views ui, the preview doesn't show a single data.

I suspect a database problem but I don't know what to do

Answer (score 0):

You can export the whole view from local server to production server, if it works it means that there must be a problem in db, so try exporting the database again. And one suggestion you can use [features module](http://drupal.org/project/features) for deployment process.

Answer (score 0):

update the database on the staging machine probably you might not have taken the latest updated for database..

still i think using the feature module to export view would be helpful in your case

[features module here](http://drupal.org/project/features)

the feature module will provide you with a module that you can directly install on your staging .
what you only need to do is just install and enable the module that feature will provide you .
go through readme.txt of module for better understanding